# C++ class member by reference

Tags: c++

Hello can anyone help me with this?
I have a class with member by reference:

```
class name{
int& broj;
string ulica;
```

And have constructor:

```
public:
kuca(int b, string s) :broj(b)
{
    ulica = s;
}
```

and info class for output

```
void info(){
cout << broj << ulica << endl;
}

};
```

When i create object and try to output it

```
int isbn = 1;
name a(isbn, "text");
a.info();
```

for reference value i am getting junk/random value it seems, while other attribute is written fine:

```
 -858993460 text
```

Comment: Show a minimal compiled program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by minimal compiled program?

Comment: I mean that it is unknown what this name  kuca means because above it there is class name.

Comment: @Vlad sry that there is typo. But You and others have answered this question correct i tested it.  This was a part of assignment and i received declaration of constructor **kuca( int b, string s) :broj(b)** will need to check if it is typo. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your ctor signature as follows:

```
kuca(int& b, string s) :broj(b)
```

note the `int&` instead of `int`.  Then, the parameter `b` will refer to the variable `isbn` rather than to some call stack location.

It should be noted that with the original signature

```
kuca(int b, string s) : broj(b)
```

you're taking a reference of the parameter that's a copy passed on the stack. So, when the info() method is called, then `broj` refers to a location on the call stack rather than to the variable `isbn`. That is why it appears to print a "random" value.

Comment: It would be better if you explained _why_ your solution works and _why_ the original code behaved as it did. A solution-only answer without any further explanation is not helpful for understanding the underlying cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write at least

```
kuca( int &b, string s) :broj(b)
      ^^^^^^
{
    ulica = s;
}
```

Otherwise variable b is a local variable/object of the constructor that will be destroyed after executing the constructor and the reference will be invalid.

Answer (score 3):

A reference member always has the danger of becoming dangling: when the original object to which the reference refers goes out of scope. In your case, this happened instantly (as the object was a temporary), but even if you follow the suggestion

```
kuca(int&b, const string&s) : broj(b), ulica(s) {}
     ^^^^^
```

you can easily get into trouble. For example

```
kuca make_kuca()
{
  int x=7;
  return {x,"bad"};
}
auto k=make_kuca();
```

when the returned object's reference member refers to a variable (`x`) that has just gone out of scope.

Therefore, reference data members should be used with care to ensure that their lifetime never exceeds that of they variable they refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing a reference to the parameter `b`, which exists only during the constructor call. After the constructor call you're left with referencing an `int` that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone already said, you probably meant this...

```
kuca(int b, string s) :broj(b)
```

to be

```
kuca(int& b, string s) :broj(b)
```

There isn't any performance benefit to passing an `int` by reference though, and the reference is invalid as soon as the `int` goes out of scope which could create a difficult bug to track down.

My personal preference is to pass by address whenever the variable can be mutated.

```
class name {

  public:
    kuca(int* b, string s) : broj(b), ulica(s);

  private:

    int* broj;
    string ulica;
}
```

That turns the above into a compile time error.  Using a reference as a class member is easy to use incorrectly.